# best width of HTML/PDF document for printing

Tags: html, pdf, printing

I'm creating HTML documents for printing, by testing I found that width of around 650px is close to the margin. It's also good for PDF documents since I need to convert the HTML to PDF if the client wishes to.

Can you tell me what is the suggested width in px for a print HTML document, that afterwards needs to be converted to PDF? I know these are relative to the DPI and stuff like that, but there should be a simpler guide to this .... e.g. most of the sites that can offer printing of certain pages, have a fixed width of around 600px for the content.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Pixels and Dots-Per-Inch are different beasts *entirely*, there is no simple way to translate from one to another. Obviously, then, I suggest not trying to do so.

Instead, I'd suggest using a print [style-sheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) and defining widths and sizes in relevant terminology for the medium, such as `pt` (point), `pc` (picas), `cm`, `mm` or `in` (centimetres, millimetres or inches)...

Answer (score 1):

Printing is generally specified in mm rather than pixels. I would suggest calculating to the paper size you're targeting.

See: http://www.unitconversion.org/unit_converter/typography.html

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to make all the parameters configurable (with some common default values): width, height, and px/pt ratio. For US you may neeed `USLetter`, for Europe, Russia - `A4`. `px/pt` is a hardware dependent parameter. You can make it configurable to fit different needs. P.S. All these come from my 6-year experience on XML to PDF software.

Comment: Certainly a page width of 1200px would be less advantageous than one of 700px, right?  Can you make a range suggestion based on your experience?

Answer (score 0):

I'm asking something specific here - have you done a similar thing before, that is having a print-ready HTML with stylesheet defined and then converting it to PDF? What is the methodology that you use, in terms of units, measures? From the posts above, seems like you haven't ... I'd rather appreciate a more concrete answer to this. Thanks.